# Unable to access internet from VM (Ubuntu 12.04) installed in Windows 7 Host OS

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Ubuntu as my guest O.S. in Vmware. I am able to ping DNS as well as Google from the terminal but unable to access the same from Firefox browser.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution:

I have edited following file

/etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 192.168.1.1